# Is OTP code 2-step verification no longer supported for Google account?

Tags: google-account, multi-factor-auth

I tried to enable 2-step verification on a new Google account. I wanted to use OTP (e.g., Google Authenticator) as before, but I could not find such options. All I could find were

```
How do you want to get codes?
()Text message   ()Phone call

Security Key
Google Prompt
```

. I thought "maybe 'Security Key' has OTP option", but no, it seemed to be only for special USB keys. Is the OTP no longer supported?

Comment: To learn about Google accounts 2SV please read [Protect your account with 2-Step Verification](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839?hl=en)

Comment: @Rubén I agree with your comment. So, does that not mean that the answer to the OP’s question is “no”? And if that is the case, would it not be better to create an answer? Just looking to learn from you :)

Comment: @Tedinoz `I agree with your comment. So, does that not mean that the answer to the OP’s question is “no”? ` No. According to the docs nowadays it's possible to use Google Authenticator and printed codes (few days ago I used printed codes). In this case I think that the OP should read the docs and updated the question accordingly to what they learned or what they found unclear.

Comment: @Ruben Groan...  How could I `agree with your comment` but not know the rest of the details? Your clarification is noted.

Comment: I wanted to do otp too, but seems google wants to keep shady stuff to itself

Answer (score 0):

I'm in Germany and the guide says it is supported, but the option isn't available in the interface.

So Google doesn't support using an authenticator OTP code for 2FA, at least in Germany

**How you sign in to Google**
[image: How you sign in to Google]

**Use your phone as a second step to sign in**
[image: Use your phone as a second step to sign in]

Comment: Your answer and images don't provide a lot of detail.  What is listed to the right of **2-Step Verification** it needs to be enabled for the option to be available.